# Traverse down a JSON depending on length of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

Say I have a json

```
jsonData = {
   "id":"dfd",
   "properties":{
      "Pri":"2",
      "Brief Description":"asdf",
      "Description":"",
      "tree":{
        "var": "2",
        "rav": "3"
      }
    }   
}
```

and a list

```
var variableArray = ['properties', 'tree', 'var'];
```

If I want to access the value of var and edit it. How would I do that while maintaining the value of jsonData?

I've tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < variableArray.length; i++) {
  jsonData = jsonData[variableArray[i]];
}
jsonData = 'new value';
```

But I can no longer access the whole jsonData.

What are some way to implement this?

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have references to properties, which is effectively what you're trying to use there.

Instead, you can give yourself a method that will traverse an object and either retrieve or assign a property in it. Here's a quick and dirty in ES5 and earlier:

```
function accessPath(obj, path, value) {
    var o = obj;
    var i = 0;
    var last = path.length - 1;
    while (i < last) {
       o = o[path[i]];
       ++i;
    }
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        // Getting
        return o[path[last]];
    } else {
        // Setting
        return o[path[last]] = value;
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
function accessPath(obj, path, value) {
    var o = obj;
    var i = 0;
    var last = path.length - 1;
    while (i < last) {
       o = o[path[i]];
       ++i;
    }
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
        // Getting
        return o[path[last]];
    } else {
        // Setting
        return o[path[last]] = value;
    }
}

var data = {
   "id":"dfd",
   "properties":{
      "Pri":"2",
      "Brief Description":"asdf",
      "Description":"",
      "tree":{
        "var": "2",
        "rav": "3"
      }
    }   
}

var path = ['properties', 'tree', 'var'];

console.log("Existing: " + accessPath(data, path));
accessPath(data, path, "new value");
console.log("Updated: " + accessPath(data, path));
console.log("Confirm: " + data.properties.tree.var);
```

Looks fairly similar in ES2015+, other than perhaps how you check if `value` is supplied.

Not pretty, but fairly efficient.

Actually, we can go further if we return an object with a getter and setter, which would look a bit like a property reference even though it isn't actually:

```
function makeAccessor(obj, path) {
    var o = obj;
    var i = 0;
    var last = path.length - 1;
    var lastName = path[last];
    while (i < last) {
       o = o[path[i]];
       ++i;
    }
    return {
        get value() {
            return o[lastName];
        },
        set value(value) {
            o[lastName] = value;
        }
    };
}
```

Then, getting the accessor:

```
var accessor = makeAccessor(data, path);
```

And using it:

```
console.log(accessor.value);
accessor.value = "new value";
```

```js
function makeAccessor(obj, path) {
    var o = obj;
    var i = 0;
    var last = path.length - 1;
    var lastName = path[last];
    while (i < last) {
       o = o[path[i]];
       ++i;
    }
    return {
        get value() {
            return o[lastName];
        },
        set value(value) {
            o[lastName] = value;
        }
    };
}

var data = {
   "id":"dfd",
   "properties":{
      "Pri":"2",
      "Brief Description":"asdf",
      "Description":"",
      "tree":{
        "var": "2",
        "rav": "3"
      }
    }   
}

var path = ['properties', 'tree', 'var'];

var accessor = makeAccessor(data, path);

console.log("Existing: " + accessor.value);
accessor.value = "new value";
console.log("Updated: " + accessor.value);
console.log("Confirm: " + data.properties.tree.var);
```

Comment: I was getting errors calling the function with only two arguments, so I made small tweaks and it is working great. The code is working great, thanks!

Comment: @Simon2233: That's odd, it works fine with two arguments in the live example above. BTW, I added a second option for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could write little helpers `read` and `write` that do what you need – note `data` is not altered by use of `read`

```js
const read = (o, [k,...ks]) =>
  o ? k === undefined ? o
                      : read (o[k], ks)
    : undefined
    
const write = (o, [k,...ks], v) =>
  o ? ks.length === 0 ? (o[k] = v, null)
                      : write (o[k], ks, v)
    : undefined
    
const data = {
  "id":"dfd",
  "properties":{
    "Pri":"2",
    "Brief Description":"asdf",
    "Description":"",
    "tree":{
      "var": "2",
      "rav": "3"
    }
  }   
}

// read
console.log (read (data, ['properties', 'tree', 'var']))
// => 2
console.log (read (data, ['foo', 'bar', 'barf']))
// => undefined (signals failure)

// write
console.log (write (data, ['properties', 'tree', 'var'], 'new value'))
// => null (signals success)
console.log (write (data, ['foo', 'bar', 'barf'], 'new value')) 
// => undefined (signals failure)

// read updated value
console.log (read (data, ['properties', 'tree', 'var'])) 
// => "new value"
```

By the way, to add to others' comments, JavaScript Object *Notation* is what JSON stands for. It's the *Notation* part that makes JSON different from "JSO" (JavaScript Object). More simply put, JSON is a *string* representation of a JavaScript Object. You'll know it's not JSON if it's not a string.

Comment: originally misread question – i didn't know we needed ability to mutate data.